# UI is missing after creating a native build from ionic vue.js project

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic vue.js project. I have existing code of web application and I want to convert this code into native mobile application. I have gone through the official documentation and successfully create build for android and iOS from the existing code. But when I run application into android studio then UI is not showing as per web output UI is lagging and some component are missing like it does not show icons and spinner values. I don't know why it is happening. I am stuck in this part only.

Comment: When I  check the log cat then i got this error when when load the web view,[AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:663: Null anb